# Did the victim of neo-Nazi violence as reported in Pink News die?

Tags: criminology, mortality, russia, violence

From [Pink News](http://www.pinknews.co.uk/2013/08/06/gay-teenager-kidnapped-and-tortured-by-russian-homophobes-believed-to-have-died-from-injuries/):

> The gay teenager who was kidnapped and tortured by Russian neo-Nazis has died from his injuries it has been claimed [by Spectrum Human Rights].
>
> ... PinkNews is unable to verify the claims ...

Going to [Spectrum Human Rights](http://www.spectrumhr.org/hot-news-1/recentneonazivictimdiesanti-naziactivistsindanger):

> According to the human right activist, Dr. Valentin Degterev, MD, who closely monitors infamous Neo Nazi group "Occupy Pedofilyaj", the Uzbek victim [...] died as a result of numerous tortures.
>
> Spectrum Human Rights was not able to obtain any official confirmation of the Uzbek victim's death.

From Valentin Degterev's [livejournal account](http://degterew-ww.livejournal.com/12383.html):

> After terrible tortures Muslim Uzbek died in the Sverdlovsk region!

Did the victim die?

Comment: There were comments this question, which lead to fixes to the question. The comments were then deleted as obsolete. There were comments on this question about the deletion of comments and a proposed competitor to Skeptics.SE. They were deleted as off-topic. If you don't like the rule that comments should be focussed on clarifying the question, please take it to meta.